# Get table name when querying data from database in Python Flask

Tags: python, mysql, json, rest, flask

Im starting to pick up Flask. After 3 years of PHP ive decided its time.
I successfully connected to my local server and database, and im able to query data from the database and output it on the screen. Then i decided its time to jump into a small REST API project, but I cant figure out how to fetch the table names to achive valid JSON output. Here is my code:

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
fetchdata = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
output = json.dumps(fetchdata)
return output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check the official MySQL docs for Python? [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html) it´s a nice example that could help you connect to your database and get the info from your table.

## ***Edit:***

With this code you could fetch all the tables in your DB and then take the ones you want.

```py
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb

db= MySQLdb.connect("hostname", "username", "password", "database_name")

cursor= db.cursor()

result = cursor.fetchall()

for i in range(len(result)):
    print(result[i])
```

Comment: i have connected to the database and i am able to query data from it, it just doesnt give me the table data i need. It gives the content (username, password, other info) but not the table name, and to form a valid json response, i need the table name.

Comment: also you could have done this in a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: oh I see now I get what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

When you say table name, do you mean column name? If so, you're looking for `cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor`, for example:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT, user=USER, passwd=PASSWD, db=DB, cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor, use_unicode=1)
```

Then after you do `cursor = connection.cursor()`, `cursor.execute(sql)`, and `all_rows = cursor.fetchall()`, you get a dictionary, which you can JSONify:

```
for row in all_rows:
    row['column_selected'] # exists :)
...
json.dumps(all_rows) # should be much better now
```

Hope I've understood your problem correctly!